# UnsatisfiedLinkError couldn't load game - cocos2d-x on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am trying to create a new cocos2d-x Project for Android and followed the following tutorial:
[Cocos2d-x Android Integration](http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started)

At the end, I get an error when I try to run the application stating:

```
10-14 21:52:37.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1568): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load game: findLibrary returned null
```

The "game" library is loaded from the generated activity:

```
         System.loadLibrary("game");
```

But there isn't anything in my project as game.so. I only have libgame.so
What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Since Cocos2d-X has hit the 2.0 series, things have really improved. Here's a newer tutorial about how to create a [Cocos2d-X meta-project for iOS, Mac, Windows and Android](http://paralaxer.com/cocos2d-x-project-setup/).

Comment: Thanks for the new Tutorial. I got the same result though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you place your .so file? Make sure it is under "libs" and maybe even "libs/armeabi" or "libs/armeabi-v7". If it already has a v7, try deleting it.

the naming convention for android turns libgame.so into "game" for loadlibrary .. your naming is correct

also make sure that you built this library with NDK or the producers of this "game" build the library with NDK (which by the naming, seems like it was!)

Seems like your having a 64-bit issue that can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=85)

Comment: The cocos2d-x script placed it at "libs/armeabi" and was created using android-ndk-r8b

Comment: Suggestion from LIBGDX; 
- use a 32-bit VM.
- use the nightlies which include Windows 64-bit VM support. The nightlies can be found at http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org. Note that they

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had to use a VM to make it work, which is a bit annoying.

Comment: Sorry to hear, but I am glad you got it to work. Native libraries are always a pain!