# Cocos2dx android application runs on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

The project was working just fine last Thursday, then, some sort of Eclipse bug caused the project properties to get all messed up.

After a splitting and frustrating headache, managed to isolate the issue and fix it....on the emulator, running it on the device gives me the original error messages:

```
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1027)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1885)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load game: findLibrary returned null
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
07-25 13:01:08.482: E/AndroidRuntime(4273):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
```

Already tried at least 12 different ways to fix the "Couldn't load game: findLibrary returned null" error to no avail.

UPDATE: Tried using a 4.0 simulator with the exact same results, so it's definitely tied to android version; however, the project was created and is indeed built for Android 4.0 as the minimum.

Any ideas what might be happening and how to fix it?

Thanks for any replies

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886004/unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-load-game-cocos2d-x-on-android  ??

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your library is not properly generated. Goto ProjectHome->libs->armeabi->libgame.so . libgame.so file is missing.
This file could be generated when you run create-android-project.bat or equivalent linux file.
which creates empty android project.Try copy paste this file from there.

Answer (score 0):

To build cocos2dx project for Android you should perform two steps.

1. Build C++ libraries. It can be done with build_native.sh
2. Build Java Project. It can be done through Eclipse.

Such error will happen if you have missed the first step.